# Multiple GPUs and Fans on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-settings

I have two GTX 1080ti on an Ubuntu 18.04 box, both of them Founder's edition. I use them mainly for training neural networks.

Now, I essentially have two problems:

1. Setting the coolbits (even with --enable-all-gpus) lets me set fan speed and clocks ***just for the GPU which is attached to the monitor***
2. I'd like not to set the fan speed statically: rather, I'd like to set a dynamic profile, %fanspeed vs temperature. Mind that when in automatic mode, under load one 1080ti regularly hits 89-90C, no matter the throttling and the fact that the case is roomy.. (the other 1080ti stays cooler.. I think that not all the gpus are created equal).

Informations about my config:

```
inxi -b
System:    Host: nimrod Kernel: 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: FUJITSU model: D3128-B2 v: S26361-D3128-B2 serial: N/A
           UEFI: FUJITSU // American Megatrends v: V4.6.5.4 R1.8.0 for D3128-B2x date: 06/28/2018
CPU:       10 core Intel Xeon E5-2680 v2 (-MT-MCP-) speed/max: 2269/3600 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430]
           Card-2: NVIDIA GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
           Card-3: NVIDIA GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: modesetting,nvidia,ati,radeon,nouveau (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 2560x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
           version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 415.27
Network:   Card: Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
           driver: e1000e
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 2262.5GB (9.5% used)
Info:      Processes: 413 Uptime: 10 min Memory: 3677.2/96560.4MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Nvidia-smi:

```
Mon Mar 25 04:19:30 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 415.27       Driver Version: 415.27       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   39C    P8    10W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 31%   57C    P0    69W / 250W |    204MiB / 11176MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    1      1465      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           201MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And finally my xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 415.27

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "31"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "31"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Note that the coolbits are set for both of them.

Can you help me?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Already tried `sensors` and `fancontrol`?

Comment: You are using the closed source `nvidia` driver for both cards, so you'll probably have to take your question to Nvidia - if they designed their system in such a way that you can only control cooling for the active GPU, then that's that.

Comment: @dirkt I understand. I'm asking this on their forum right now, but I thought that maybe someone else here could have coped with the same problem.

Comment: @Xen2050 Actually, no. I'll try them. I didn't know `fancontrol`, but if I'm not making mistakes, I think that `sensors` is just for reading sensors.

Comment: @Xen2050 By `fancontrol` you mean this: https://github.com/foucault/nvfancontrol ?

Comment: I meant the package just called `fancontrol`, it's in Debian & Ubuntu's repositories (and probably every distro based on them). It uses `sensors` (from lm-sensors)for reading temperatures & fan speeds, then tells the kernel to speed up or slow down fans, if they're controllable. I'm not sure if they can see your video card's sensors & fans though.  `nvfancontrol` sounds promising, but says "It is a work in progress so proceed with caution!"

Comment: `fancontrol` won't work as long as the drivers for the hardware where the fans are attached don't publish this to the kernel. To my knowledge the closed-source nvidia driver doesn't do this, while `nouveau` might. But it doesn't hurt to check. You might also try `lm-sensors`.

Comment: mmhh.. Strange. lm-sensors works, since the Psensor indicator GUI shows both GPU fans rpms and percentage (and GPUs temps as well). But the `sensors` command does show just the cpu temps..
In order to try and configure fancontrol, I understand one has to get sensors command to catch the fan speed, am I right?

Comment: fancontrol reads info from the kernel, in /sys "files", if you can read temps & fan speeds somewhere in there then you can attempt the next part of the problem: controlling the fans. See fancontrol's man page & it's pwmconfig script

Comment: Man it's realy frustrating doing this in 2019 :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have experienced exactly the same thing last week. It's the driver's fault. Try version 390 or 430, they are the two versions I confirmed to work properly on arch, with two 1080ti.

It's really hard to identify the problem. At first I thought it's my motherboard's fault who doesn't support SLI, so I used another motherboard and activated SLI, then I can set fan speed for both GPUs. However, when using SLI, the two graphic cards were using the same memories on two GPUs. This is unacceptable because SLI make batch size smaller. Then I inactivate SLI, and I'm unable to set fan speed for both cards again. So I tried to change my nvidia driver, which then works properly.
Damn nvidia, I broke the LGA base on the first motherboard when I change another motherboard instead, and burned an i5-9400f because of the broken base. I know it's due to my carelessness, but I wouldn't have to suffer if were not for nvidia drivers' bug.(just some nonsense complains)

Comment: Mmmhh, one does not need SLI for deep learning (if you mean proper SLI, that is, the physical connection via the plastic bridge). For parallel training, it is sufficient to use the pcie bus. 
Coming to the fans, let us see if I'm understanding you. Without the SLI bridge, I won't be able to set both fans, and that's even with 390 or 430 drivers. Am I right?

Comment: @MadHatter Sorry for my bad expression. I mean driver 390 and 430 are comfirmed by me to set GPU fans properly. Actually I'm now using 430 for the two 1080ti on my archlinux. I can set both gpu fans speed in nvidia-settings without SLI. I mention SLI and other stuff just for complaining. SLI is not necessary for deep learning for sure.

Comment: @MadHatter OK, let me get it straight. First you just change your driver to other version. I don't know the right version for your OS, but I'm pretty sure that driver 390 and 430 on archlinux(it's manjaro-kde acutually) are able to set multiple gpus fan speed. Second, use command like nvidia-xconfig or just edit xorg.conf directly to set --coolbits(don't forget --enable-all-gpus). Finally, reboot. If not working, try another version of nvidia driver.

Comment: Thanks, it's crystal clear. As soon as I can afford a bit of downtine, I'll upgrade the drivers (I'm with 410 as of now) and try. But if you succeeded with manjaro, I'm fairly sure I'll succeed with ubuntu as well.. Let's hope that future drivers release won't break the ball. Thanks!